# Rails incorrect date query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, timezone

I have problem with ActiveRecord queries. I suppose that it connected with Time Zone.
This is example

```
date_start = Date.parse(params[:filter][:date_start]).beginning_of_day
date_end = Date.parse(params[:filter][:date_start]).end_of_day
data = MyModel.where("created_at>=? and created_at <=?", date_start, date_end)
```

If params are
    params[:filter][:date_start] is "10.07.16" and params[:filter][:date_end] is "15.07.16"
Dates in resulting query will be incorrect. The resulting dates will be [correct date] - [zone time diff]. So insted of 2016-07-16 00:00 for start_end I have 2016-07-15 21:00

Comment: first change the date format ... it should be like 
 Date.parse("16.07.10") #yymmdd
=> Sun, 10 Jul 2016

Comment: But Date.parse parsing my date correct. Why I should change it?

Comment: Ok your problem is in the query level ..

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to use the time zone

`Time.zone.now` and `Time.now`

Instead of using `Date.parse`  use `Time.zone.parse`. Here is more details to get the time zone dates . With different dates you can find different values .

`date_start = Time.zone.parse(params[:filter][:date_start]).beginning_of_day
 date_end = Time.zone.parse(params[:filter][:date_start]).end_of_day
 data = MyModel.where("created_at beween ? and ?", date_start, date_end)`